# For of and for loop different results

Tags: javascript, for-loop, spread, for-of-loop

Can anyone explain, why the first solution using a regular for loop infinitely loops, whereas the second solution using a for of loop doesn’t.  The code is identical, so I would expect the same results.

```
const flatten = (arr) => {
    let newArr = []
    for (i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
            newArr = [...newArr, ...flatten(arr[i])]
            console.log(newArr)
        } else {
            newArr.push(arr[i])
        }
    }
    return newArr
}
// const flatten = (arr) => {
//     let newArr = []
//     for (let el of arr) {
//       if (Array.isArray(el)) {
//           console.log(el, 'i am el')
//         newArr = [...newArr, ...flatten(el)]
//         console.log(newArr)
//       } else {
//         newArr.push(el)
//         console.log(el, 'i am just reg non array element')
//       }
//     }
//     return newArr
//   }
flatten([[1],[2],3,[[4,5]], [6, 7]])
```

Comment: you forgot to initialize i in the conditional loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a `var` or `let` declaration for `i` in your `for` loop to make it local, so every time you call `flatten` the value gets reset. Change

```
for (i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
```

to

```
for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
```

and the code works as expected:

```js
const flatten = (arr) => {
    let newArr = []
    for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
            newArr = [...newArr, ...flatten(arr[i])]
        } else {
            newArr.push(arr[i])
        }
    }
    return newArr
}
console.log(flatten([[1],[2],3,[[4,5]], [6, 7]]))
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks Nick. I totally missed that.  Now it works as expected.

Comment: @Altaf no worries - sometimes it just takes a second pair of eyes...